# Pyspark: Use ffmpeg on the driver and workers

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, ffmpeg, databricks

I'm trying to process a batch of audio files on my Spark cluster (in Databricks). I have an init script that installs ffmpeg (with `apt`) and pydub (with `pip`).

I have a Dataframe of the file paths I want to process, when I call my UDF that opens/processes/exports I sometimes get the following error:

```
pydub.exceptions.CouldntEncodeError: Encoding failed. ffmpeg/avlib returned error code: 1
...
[wav @ 0x1e1b4c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 
(Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, 768 kb/s): unspecified sample format
```

that is to say, my UDF which uses pydub can correctly process some files, but for some other it fails. I checked with the `file` command, all these MP3 files seem to have the same configuration/codec. So I'm thinking that pyspark distributes the 'lines' in my dataframe to the driver and the worker, but only the driver has ffmpeg. So all the files that are processed by my worker fail.

Is my assumption correct?

How can I solve this? I don't know how to either:

- Do the processing only on the driver (which has all the requirments)
- Install ffmpeg on the worker too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, need to install ffmpeg which is the dependency for pydub on all nodes with `init Scripts`.
   This can be implemented by using the code below in the databricks cell

```
dbutils.fs.mkdirs("dbfs:/databricks/scripts/") #create a new dir
dbutils.fs.put("/databricks/scripts/installffmpeg.sh",
"""
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install ffmpeg
""", True) #create an init script into the newly created dir
```

Then go to Clsusters -> Edit -> Advanced Options - Init Scripts to add the dir to the File Path
[image]

2. Choose `Confirm`

Now the ffmpeg will be installed when you start your cluster

3. Go to Libraries, install New, type your pydub package and version here:
   [image]

Click `install`

Done!

Comment: you don't need to restart cluster after installation of library. it's only required when you uninstall library

Comment: Thanks for the response, I solved my issue but I did not use this answer. Plus, can you edit your post to format it better?

Comment: @AlexOtt, Thanks for that, but the restart step is after add the init script not install the library.

Comment: is there any other way to install it? Because I don't have permission on the cluster.